# How to make a bot for a wikia, if possible, using javascript

Tags: bots, wikia

i would like to know how to make a bot that will connect to a wikia with using javascript, i already made a bot that connects to discord, but would like to know how to do it for the wikia

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: I may suggest you to search online and look for existing JavaScript bots.